# CoinBase App limits Requests

Tags: coinbase.com

Coin base recently prohibited me from making a bitcoin request with a pop up saying I already made too many requests.  I had maybe 3 requests that day.  Any one else see this?  What is the purpose of limiting requests?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#rate-limiting

The limit is quite high, it is really strange you received an error response. I suggest you to contact their support, and meanwhile changing your API key (if you're using one) could be a good idea.